# Synonymize/merge [gpu-programming] into [gpu]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

The [tag info for [gpu-programming]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/gpu-programming/info) simply says

> See the tag entry for [gpu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gpu).

I don't see any noticeable difference in questions tagged [gpu-programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gpu-programming) and [gpu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gpu). Should we synonymize/merge them?

<sub>My apologies for the lack of puns in the title. I simply couldn't think of any...</sub>

Comment: The parallel overhead of having [gpu] and [gpu-programming] does indeed seem to lead to inefficiency.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, we should. And, now we have:

#### [gpu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gpu) ← [gpu-programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gpu-programming)

As I like to remind people, virtually every tag here has an implicit "-programming" suffix, since that's all that is on-topic for Stack Overflow, so there is no need for that to explicitly appear in a tag. There's definitely no need to have a *separate* tag.